# A concise way to access an element of a set in pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, networking, distributed-computing, pseudocode

Let ***networklocs*** be a set of elements of the form *(n, t, l)* where *n* is a node in the network, *t* is a clock tick and l is the location of *n* at time *t*. How can I get (in a concise way in pseudo-code) the element of networklocs where node and time is given?

I know I can write a function like

```
    getElement(ni,t)
    for all (nj,t',l') in networklocs
      if nj=ni and t'= t then return (nj,t',l')
```

But is there a more concise way to access an element of the set ***networklocs*** in the pseudo-code?

**Note that I would like to keep networklocs as a set, so solutions with maps or arrays do not fit.**

Comment: In pseudocode you write whatever you want, provided people understand you. That's why we call it pseudocode. `networklocs[node=ni,time=t]` is as good as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Note that returning ni and t is useless because they're already known. In notation and practice, you'd want

```
Let M be a map: <N, T> -> L
```

The operation you want is just a map lookup:

```
l <- M <n, t>
```

Although the map is the most likely notation, a predicate logic expression can also be used:

```
Let get(n,t) be x = <n, t, l> | x \in networklocs
```

The loop you provided as an example is neither correct nor pseudocode. It's a concrete implementation of a map, and it doesn't say what to do when the key is not found.

Comment: :Thanks, but for some reasons I would like to keep networklocs as a set for the pseudocode. I know that with a map is easier to write but here I want to know how can I write if with a set!

Comment: @BenBost There's no reason you can't define the data as a set and then define the map, too, when it's needed.  Pseudocode that does a linear lookup in a list isn't pseudoocode. It's implementation.  I'll add one more suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, but I am sorry I am not interested in the implementation, I assure you I knew I could use a map when I sent the question and as I said the function I proposed was not the way that i thought the pseudo-code should be written, hence I asked the question. And, your proposition is not clear. You say although the map is the most likely notation we can use this logic expression : "Let get(n,t) be x? you use get with two keys as you use it on a map, here I only  wanted to use a set.

Comment: @BenBost Sorry I can't meet your requirements. I've written quite a few published papers on algorithms and read hundreds. I'm telling you the way it would be done in the computer science literature. If you're out for something else, I wish you luck.